# Understanding CoffeeScript Function w/ ProtoType Field

Tags: javascript, oop, coffeescript

An exercise from [CoffeeScript: Accelerated JavaScript Development](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript) asks "what's wrong with the following code?"

```
Genie = ->
  Genie::wishesLeft = 3
  Genie::grantWish = ->
    if @wishesLeft > 0
      console.log "wish granted!"
      --@wishesLeft
```

My understanding is that `Genie::wishesLeft = 3` **incorrectly** assigns this property to the `Genie prototype`.

Here's what I think the re-factor should be:

```
Genie = (@wishesLeft)->
  @wishesLeft = 3
  ...
```

I say this since I would expect each `Genie` object to have its own `wishesLeft` property.  However, the following code seems to behave normally:

```
genie1 = new Genie()
console.log genie1.grantWish(), "wishes left"
console.log genie1.grantWish(), "wishes left"
console.log genie1.grantWish(), "wishes left"
```

**output**

```
$coffee SpotTheBug.coffee
wish granted!
2 'wishes left'
wish granted!
1 'wishes left'
wish granted!
0 'wishes left'
```

What's the problem with the above code? How's my re-factor?

Comment: Never assign to the prototype inside the constructor.

Comment: One problem is that modifying the prototype can effectively modify all instances.

Comment: @KevinMeredith: Because instantiating one object should not affect the other instances. There might be (questionable) exceptions (when prototype properties are used as "static" class attributes), but it's a good rule of thumb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real problem isn't how the prototype is used, the real problem is a combination of two things:

1. The implicit return value from functions.
2. The code is trying to hand-craft a class-function instead of letting CoffeeScript sort that out by using `class`.

If you have a look at the JavaScript-ified version of this:

```
Genie = ->
  Genie::wishesLeft = 3
  Genie::grantWish = ->
    if @wishesLeft > 0
      console.log "wish granted!"
      --@wishesLeft
```

then we'll see what's going wrong:

```
var Genie = function() {
  Genie.prototype.wishesLeft = 3;
  return Genie.prototype.grantWish = function() {
    if (this.wishesLeft > 0) {
      console.log("wish granted!");
      return --this.wishesLeft;
    }
  };
};
```

Notice the implicitly added `return Genie.prototype.grantWish`? That means that `g = new Genie` will actually leave the `grantWish` method in `g` and `g.grantWish()` will give you TypeError.

From the [fine `new` operator manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

> When the code `new foo(...)` is executed, the following things happen:
>
> 1. A new object is created, inheriting from *foo.prototype*.
> 2. [...]
> 3. The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole new expression. [...]

Note that **3** says about the constructor function's return value.

One solution is to manually specify the return value so that the implicit one doesn't screw up `new`'s behavior:

```
Genie = ->
  Genie::wishesLeft = 3
  Genie::grantWish = ->
    if @wishesLeft > 0
      console.log "wish granted!"
      --@wishesLeft
  return # <---------------- Add this
```

[**Demo**](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aGenie%20=%20-%3E%0A%20%20Genie%3a%3awishesLeft%20=%203%0A%20%20Genie%3a%3agrantWish%20=%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20if%20@wishesLeft%20%3E%200%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%20%22wish%20granted!%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20--@wishesLeft%0A%20%20return%0A%0Ag1%20=%20new%20Genie%0Ag2%20=%20new%20Genie%0A%0Ag1.grantWish%28%29%0Aconsole.log%20g1.wishesLeft%0Aconsole.log%20g2.wishesLeft)

A better solution would be write CoffeeScript rather than JavaScript when working in CoffeeScript. This would mean using `class` to deal with all this stuff for you:

```
class Genie
  wishesLeft: 3
  grantWish: ->
    if @wishesLeft > 0
      console.log "wish granted!"
      --@wishesLeft
```

[**Demo**](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Genie%0A%20%20wishesLeft%3a%203%0A%20%20grantWish%3a%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20if%20@wishesLeft%20%3E%200%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%20%22wish%20granted!%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20--@wishesLeft%0A%0Ag1%20=%20new%20Genie%0Ag2%20=%20new%20Genie%0Aconsole.log%20g1%0A%0Ag1.grantWish%28%29%0Aconsole.log%20g1.wishesLeft%0Aconsole.log%20g2.wishesLeft)

Comment: in the [first example](http://jsfiddle.net/XaxpL/1/), why am I seeing `g()` evaluate to `undefined`? I would've expected `this.wishesLeft` to equal `2` (3-1). Also, I'm curious why `g.wishesLeft` is undefined.

Comment: Because `g` is not a `Genie`, it is just the `grantWish` function. Note what I said about the behavior of `new` and see what `console.log(g)` has to say. BTW, you can use CoffeeScript at jsfiddle.net by selecting CoffeeScript in the **Languages** panel in the sidebar.